# Funding for small astrobiology fieldwork project

Tags: mars, cost, astrobiology

I am a postdoctoral scholar who plans to conduct a small project at the MDRS, a Mars simulation volunteer project. The project will be to conduct DNA sequencing of soil samples using a handheld nano pore sequencer. It could be a proof-of-principle that sequencing research can be successful in remote areas without sequencing facilities and under "planetary exploration simulation" protocols.

I am hoping to obtain funding to cover the travel (\$1,000), substinence (\$1,500 participation fee at MDRS), and equipment (\$1,500 for sequencer and reagants). I would definitely apply to multiple funding sources to increase my chance and in case they each could only cover a part of the expenses. The project will be in April 2020.

I recently unsuccessfully applied to the Lewis and Clark Astrobiology Fund and am currently trying to find other funding sources. This has been difficult for me as I have little prior funding applications for this type of fieldwork. **My main question is: Do you know of funding opportunities for which this type of project might be considered?**

Many thanks for sharing any ideas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about space exploration.

Comment: *I recently unsuccessfully applied* Did you get any feedback?

Comment: @JanDoggen just fyi the OP has written a reply to you but says they've been blocked from commenting because less than 50 reputation (may be related to being unregistered). Currently the reply exists as a pending edit to the question.